# Get command line parameters with argparse

Tags: python, bash, python-2.7, argparse

I´m trying to use argparse of Python but I cannot get a command line parameter.

Here my code:

```
DEFAULT_START_CONFIG='/tmp/config.json'

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Start the Cos service and broker for development purposes.')
parser.add_argument('-c', '--config', default=DEFAULT_START_CONFIG, action=FileAction, type=str, nargs='?',
                help='start configuration json file (default:' +  DEFAULT_START_CONFIG + ')')

args = parser.parse_args()
```

But then when I run my python script like:

```
./start.py -c /usr/local/config.json
```

Instead of getting this path it is getting the default value defined (`/tmp/config.json`).

```
print args.config ---> "/tmp/config.json"
```

What I´m doing wrong here?

Comment: Hopefully, `DEFAULT_START_CONFIG='/tmp/config.json'` and it's defined within the script ?

Comment: yes, has quotes and it´s defined in the script

Comment: I'm surprised it ran without error, with that unknown `FileAction`.

Comment: It was not unknown, it´s just that a colleague did that class, and I did not notice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The standard documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) doesn't mention `FileAction`. Instead there's a class [FileType](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#filetype-objects) intended for `type` argument, not for `action`.

So I would write something like this:

```
DEFAULT_START_CONFIG='/tmp/config.json'

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Start the Cos service and broker for development purposes.')
parser.add_argument('-c', '--config', default=DEFAULT_START_CONFIG,
    type=argparse.FileType('r'), help='start configuration json file')
args = parser.parse_args()
print(args)
```

This gives me the following:

```
$ python test3.py
Namespace(config=<open file '/tmp/config.json', mode 'r' at 0x7fd758148540>)
$ python test3.py -c
usage: test3.py [-h] [-c CONFIG]
test3.py: error: argument -c/--config: expected one argument
$ python test3.py -c some.json
usage: test3.py [-h] [-c CONFIG]
test3.py: error: argument -c/--config: can't open 'some.json': [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'some.json'
$ touch existing.json
$ python test3.py -c existing.json
Namespace(config=<open file 'existing.json', mode 'r' at 0x7f93e27a0540>)
```

You may subclass `argparse.FileType` to something like `JsonROFileType` which would check if the supplied file is actually a JSON of expected format etc, but this seems to be out of the scope of the question.

Comment: That was exactly the problem